# JavaScript is not working inside the add more button which contain the dropdown and field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem is, the *add more button* contains two fields: drop-down menu and comment field. When I select drop-down menu as completed then comment field is required. The JavaScript is working fine for the fields which is not inside the add more button.

Below is my code:

**HTML**

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="new.php">
    <!-- Select Basic -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Status</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select id="status" name="status[]" class="form-control" >
                <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                <option value="Work in process">Work in process</option>
                <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Comment</label>  
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="commentss" name="comment[]" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" /> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input_fields" style="color:black">
        <button class="add_field btn " onclick="incrementValue()" >Add More</button>
    <div>

    <input type="text" name="mytextt[]" hidden="" >
</div>
</div>
</div>

<button id="save_btn" name="save_btn" type="submit" onclick="validate();" class="btn btn-success" >Save</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var input=document.getElementById("status");
        var comm=document.getElementById('commentss')
        var inputelement=input.value;

        if (inputelement=="Completed") {
            comm.required=true;
        }
        else {
            comm.required=false;
        }

    }
</script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field"); //Add button ID
    var wrapper_pre1         = $(".present_fields_1"); //Fields wrapper
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count

    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();

    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).prepend('<div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label status" for="selectbasic" style="">Status</label><div class="col-md-6"><select id="status" name="status[]"  class="form-control status"><option value="Pending">Pending</option><option value="Work in process">Work in process</option><option value="Completed">Completed</option></select></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-4 control-label comment" for="textinput" style="">Comment</label><div class="col-md-4"><input id="comments" name="comment[]" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md comment" style=""></div></div>')
    }
});
```

Comment: id="status" here id is a unique you cannot have more than one id on same page. so it ll work fine only with first select. try to use class.

Comment: ok i have specified different id name.the  javascript is not working still@Omi

Comment: whats your problem not getting exactly

Answer (score 1):

You are wrapping elements twice in `$`. $(add_button) and $(wrapper) are undefined which is forcing the script to stop executing. Your click handler should be as follows:

```
  add_button.click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();

    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        wrapper.prepend(...);
    }
});
```